# Functional equation $f(x*y) = f(f(x)*f(y))$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Find all endo-functions $f$ on a commutative semigroup $(\mathbb{S},*)$ such that
$f(x*y) = f(f(x)*f(y))$.

Typical case of interest are $(\mathbb{N},+)$ or $(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z},+)$ or $(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z},.)$.

QUESTION : Has anyone seen this before?

I like to call them *mo-morphisms* ( phonetically it repeats as in the right hand side of the equation).

The motivation comes from the function $f(n) = n \mod 10$ ( any base will do ) on $(\mathbb{N},+)$.
Another example on $(\mathbb{N},.)$ is $f(n):= rad(n)$. The product of the primes dividing $n$ (each prime counted once). It is easy to see that $rad(x.y)=rad(rad(x).rad(y))$.

Comment: Any such function induces a commutative semigroup structure $\tilde *$ on $f({\mathbb S})$ by $f(x) \tilde * f(y) := f(x*y) = f(f(x) * f(y))$, and the restriction of $f$ to $f({\mathbb S})$ obeys the simpler law $x \tilde * y = f(x) \tilde * f(y)$; conversely, these axioms imply the original property.  When ${\mathbb S}$ is a group, the latter condition is equivalent to $f(x) = x \tilde * a$ for some order two element $a$ of $(f({\mathbb S}), \tilde *)$.

Comment: @Joseph at start I had the involutive axiom  in (N,+) a lot but not all functions obey the idempotency.

Comment: @Terry Ok for associativity , for Z/kZ,: I have the solution for the additive but not yet for the multiplicative case your observation help clarifying.

Comment: The operation $*$ does not satisfy the identity f(xyz)=f(f(x)f(y)f(z)) in the case when $\mathbb{S}=\mathbb{Z}_2$, $*$ is addition modulo $2$ (XOR), and f(x)=x+1 mod 2 (NOT). If we added the assumption that $f=f^2$, then we would satisfy the identity f(xyz)=f(f(x)f(y)f(z)) though.

Comment: It seems to me like the way to get these is take a congruence on your semigroup and a set of representatives and let f be the map taking an element to its representative.

Comment: I guess the taking representatives for a congruence gets all the idempotent ones.

Comment: @Steinberg On (Z/2nZ,+)  f(x) = (x+n) mod 2n is not idempotent yet it a momorphism.

Comment: I only claimed the idempotent ones arise this way. Not that they are all idempotents

Comment: @Steinberg Sorry you are right.